# How to detect when the class attribute of DOM elements changes?

Tags: javascript, html, selection

This is going to take a bit of explaining. I'm using the jquery playlist thing, with JWplayer, and basically what it does is it reads the playlist .xml file, and generates a scroll menu like this:

```
<div class="jw_playlist_playlist">
   <div class="jw_playlist_item even">
      <div class="jw_playlist_title">Title</div>
      <div class="jw_playlist_description"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="jw_playlist_item odd">
      <div class="jw_playlist_title">Title2</div>
      <div class="jw_playlist_description"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

and when an item is selected, it changes to `<div class="jw_playlist_item even playing">` or `<div class="jw_playlist_item odd">`. Is there a way I can detect this change with javascript, and extract the title?

Comment: There isn't really any sane way of detecting changes to the DOM. DOM mutation events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Mutation_events) are deprecated, the support is flaky (notably attribute mutation doesn't work attribute modification, i.e. the thing you need), and the successor API ([mutation observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/MutationObserver)) only works in Chrome and FF. I'd look at documentation for the playlist plugin to see if it fires off custom events when an item is selected.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could create a timer in JavaScript and check every X seconds if the element exists.

```
<script> 

var title = ""; 

$(function() { // wait till page is loaded

    // sets a timer to repeat the function every 1 second
    setInterval(function() { 
        // if .play class div exists, take the title of the song
        if ($(".play").length > 0) { 
            title = $(".play jw_playlist_title").html();
            updateData();
        } else { 
        // otherwise set the title to be empty
            title = ""; 
        } 
     }, 1000); 

});

function updateData() {
    $("#demo").html("Current Song: "+title);
}


 </script> 

 <p id="demo">My First Paragraph</p>
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to how i'd use this.

Comment: Just attach this timer to your javascript and the variable `title` will contain the title of the currently playing song. And it will change when the song has been changed. PS. You will need jQuery.

Comment: Sorry, I'm absolutely woeful at javascript. Would this be the right way to output it? 
`<script>
var title = "";
setTimeout(function() {
 if ($(".play").length > 0) {
   title = $(".play jw_playlist_title").html();
   // or stuff //
 } else {
   title = "";
 }
}, 1000);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=title;
</script>

<p id="demo">My First Paragraph</p>`

Comment: Nope, didn't work. Actually, where are you getting "play" from? The div outside the div with the title says playing, but it alternates between odd and even.

Comment: Well you said it changes to `<div class="jw_playlist_item even playing">` and as you see there is a class tag `playing`. Do you have jQuery added to your project?